# Trouble branching DAGs in Airflow Taskflow API

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow. Using Taskflow API, I am trying to dynamically change the flow of DAGs. If a condition is met, the two step workflow should be executed a second time.

After defining two functions/tasks, if I fix the DAG sequence as below, everything works fine.

```
@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2))
def genesis(**kwargs):
    @task()
    def extract():
       print("X")
    @task()
    def add_timeframe():
       print("Y")

    extracted_data = extract()
    timeframe_data = add_timeframe(extracted_data)
```

However, I write any conditional logic to trigger the second run (either inside a DAG or after the function/task definitions), I get the error below. The error seems to be about setting upstream tasks. But the older "task.set_upstream(task2)" commands don't work in Taskflow Airflow 2.0.

All examples I could find of conditionally branching were based on the non Taskflow API. Please help.

```
@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2))
def genesis(**kwargs):
    @task()
    def extract():
       print("X")
       if <condition>:
           extracted_data2 = extract()
           timeframe_data2 = add_timeframe(extracted_data2)
    @task()
    def add_timeframe():
       print("Y")

    extracted_data = extract()
    timeframe_data = add_timeframe(extracted_data)

ERROR - Tried to create relationships between tasks that don't have DAGs yet. Set the DAG for at least one task  and try again: [<Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): add_timeframe>, <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): extract>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1086, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1260, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1300, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 233, in execute
    return_value = self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/genesis.py", line 77, in extract
    timeframe_data = add_timeframe(extracted_data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 294, in factory
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 91, in __call__
    obj.set_xcomargs_dependencies()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 722, in set_xcomargs_dependencies
    apply_set_upstream(arg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 711, in apply_set_upstream
    apply_set_upstream(elem)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 708, in apply_set_upstream
    self.set_upstream(arg.operator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1239, in set_upstream
    self._set_relatives(task_or_task_list, upstream=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1205, in _set_relatives
    "task  and try again: {}".format([self] + task_list)
```

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example of a DAG that leads to the error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example